# Equivalence of circuit networks (circuit analysis)

Tags: circuit-analysis

For the rule of equivalence, it was stated that "Two resistive 1-port networks are equivalent if and only if they have the same current-voltage (I-V) characteristics across their respective terminal-pairs for ALL loads (including sources)".

I am not sure what "For R=2" or "For R=6" means for the attached question and solution. Is it that since there are 2 resistors (R=2, R=6) in network B, the load resistor of both networks should be set to each R=2 and R=6? Then, what if the resistors in network A are R=2 and R=5, not R=2 and R=2?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Network A and Network B are equal if they have the same voltage or current source and same source resistance assuming they have the same load. Generally, you may want to think that the load can be interchanged while keeping the source network intact. So, equivalence means equivalence of voltage and current sources and source resistance. Even if the load carries same current and voltage with \$R_S\$ = 2Ω and \$R_L\$ = 5Ω,  Network A is not equivalent to Network B.

Comment: To add more details: Equivalence of networks means Thevenin and norton circuit equivalents. It is easy to see that two networks are equal if their Thevenin and norton equivalents are same. If somehow your circuits had same Thevenin voltage source or Norton current sources  with same source resistance, they could have been equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

Amit spells it out, bluntly. But I think the instructor, in preparing this question, is trying to ascertain whether or not you've acquired a very basic thinking tool about Thevenin/Norton equivalents. In short, whether or not you understand the meaning of the word *equivalent* in this context.

The question's **trick** is to provide two different circuits with the same loop current. You might be confused by this, thinking that if the load currents are the same then the circuits are *equivalent* in this way. But the question is really about the equivalence of the indicated *networks*. It's not about being *equivalent* in the sense that the load experiences the same current *in this particular case*.

If you ***do*** understand the question, then you can immediately see that the indicated pair of networks are *in no possible way* equivalent. One has a Thevenin voltage of \$4\:\text{V}\$ and a Thevenin resistance of \$2\:\Omega\$ and this is completely and obviously ***not the same*** as a Thevenin voltage of \$8\:\text{V}\$ and a Thevenin resistance of \$6\:\Omega\$.

They aren't even close and you don't need a microscope or any algebra to figure that out. You should be able to breeze through this question in seconds.

The solution *proves* that they aren't by coming up with a single case. But they could have picked any load value *other than* \$2\:\Omega\$ and made the same proof.

A visual way to see this is that the network on the left side creates a curve on an **x**-**y** chart. So does the network on the right side. But they aren't the same curves. Instead, they just happen to intersect at a load resistance of \$2\:\Omega\$:

[image]

Those are clearly ***not*** the same networks driving the load. But they do just happen to meet up with the same loop current at one value for the load.

(The above chart was generated using the Desmos plotting calculator.)

P.S. If you ever want to double-check yourself, just imagine shorting the load. If the two networks ***still*** produce the same current in the short-circuit wire then they are probably the same. You can also just look at the output voltage if you removed the load and left the network wires open, instead of loaded. If it is still the same output voltage (obviously, it's not) then they may be equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

> *I am not sure what "For R=2" or "For R=6" means for the attached
> question and solution.*

They are talking about the load resistor. That is the only resistor designated "R". You can double-check this by following the math in the example.

> *what is the resistors in network A are R=2 and R=5, not R=2 and R=2?*

It's an easy calculation but, I can tell you this that with any dual loading combinations, the two networks will always be found to be different.